# Permanently exclude words from spell checking

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, spell-check

I am editing a doc with a lot of surnames and proper nouns.  I have gone through the Spell Check and ignored all of them and they disappear.  However, when I send the doc or save it, they reappear when it is opened again.

How can I get Word to accept the words I have asked it to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

Type the word. When you get a red underline, right-click it and select "Add to dictionary". Do this for each word and they won't be highlighted as incorrect ever again ;)

The only disadvantage is that these words would be highlighted once you open the document on a different PC. Unfortunately, there isn't much you can do about this except add those words to the dictionary on those computers too.

You can also add the words in one PC, export the dictionary, and then import that dictionary in all other PCs... (https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/870-word-import-and-export-custom-dictionaries.html ) Here's how:

> Step 1: On the source computer, copy the custom dictionaries in
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UProof to an
>   intermediate location that the destination computer can access.
>
> Step 2: On the destination computer, click File > Options, select the
>   Proofing and click the Custom Dictionaries (In Word 2007, click the
>   Microsoft Office Button, and then click Word Options).
>
> Step 3: Click Add to import the custom dictionaries from intermediate
>   location.

Note: If you have several dictionaries to export, you have to repeat step3 several times. Some examples of intermediate locations that the destination computer can access include an e-mail account, a floppy disk, or a CD

Comment: You can also turn spell check of permanently, but I wouldn't recommend doing that...

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. you can add those words to your custom dictionary so Office applications will consider them to be correct in all documents.
2. you can disable spell checking parts of a document:

   - at first make sure language is visible in the status bar (bottom line) of Word, if not, just right click it and select "language"
   - select the word(s) you want to exclude, click the language in the status bar, then check "Do not check spelling or grammar"